# Bearing and location

Tags: android, google-maps, bearing

Got some strange thing here while doing task of map rotation around user current location marker. So what i am trying to do is like google maps application on second "Current location" tap. Marker must keep its position at map center while map is moving.

As i understood need to use bearing value to update camera position object on GoogleMap v2.

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdatePos;
            CameraPosition.Builder currentPlaceBuilder = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(loc);
            if (location.hasBearing())
                currentPlaceBuilder.bearing(location.getBearing());
            cameraUpdatePos = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(currentPlaceBuilder.build());
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdatePos);
```

The bug is about every location returns every time false hasBearing() call result and bearing 0.0 with my app. But google maps app shows me my direction at this time properly.

I am using service

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(gmsCallbacks)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(gmsCallbacks)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(25 * 1000)
                .setFastestInterval(5 * 1000)
                .setSmallestDisplacement(1);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                .setAlwaysShow(true);`
```

and method onconnected

```
`@Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected");
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, gmsCallbacks);
            if (locationChangeCallback != null)
                locationChangeCallback.onLocationChanged(location);
        }`
```

Does anybody knows how google map made their bearing calculation for auto orientation map mode ?
Maybe someone has such situation and could help me with advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

May this helps you

```
public class GoogleApiActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener , {
SupportMapFragment fragment;
GoogleMap googleMap;
GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
Marker marker;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_api);
    mapLoading();
    googleClientApi();


}

private void mapLoading(){
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.map_space);
    if (fragment == null)
    {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_space, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (googleMap == null){
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Map Ready CallBack", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    this.googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    this.googleMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    this.googleMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    this.googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    this.googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
}


private void googleClientApi(){
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle){
    LocationRequest locationRequest = createLocationRequest();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, createLocationRequest(),GoogleApiActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i){

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult){

}


public LocationRequest createLocationRequest()
{
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(0);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
    return locationRequest;
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    if (googleApiClient != null)
    {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    if (googleApiClient != null)
    {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Inside onLocationChanged  "+location.getAccuracy(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (location != null)
    {
        if (marker == null){
            marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                    .title("My Location"));
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 18));
        }else{
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
            updateCameraBearing(googleMap, location.getBearing(),location);
        }
    }    }

private void updateCameraBearing(GoogleMap googleMap, float bearing, Location location) {
    if ( googleMap == null) return;
    CameraPosition camPos = CameraPosition
            .builder(
                    googleMap.getCameraPosition() // current Camera
            ).target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()))
            .bearing(bearing)
            .build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPos));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but i have already tried this. The problem is the bearing value is pretty always is zero value. And i realized that google maps using compass sensors for some reason. I believe the google app is using these sensors like accelerometer and megnetic. But when i am using such sensors i don`t get the same behavior. All i get is antsy map and high loaded cpu.